# google ad not visible in UC browser, so have any alternative option for earn money from UC browser?

Tags: adsense, mobile-browser, ads, uc-browser

I have 50% traffic from UC browser. And in new version of UC browser not visible google ads, so how can I generate good revenue from my website?

I have used UC Union ad network from last 7 days but it generate $0 revenue. I am so worry about my low revenue.

Is there any alternative option for generate good revenue from UC browser?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways actually,

- Tie up with UC-union to display Ads. It is similar to Google DFP platform, and available for publisher & advertiser both.
- Serve thru Adsense (olx.in does that)
- Get your site white listed by tie up with them (their China team handles that). I do not know about money part if that is fixed or on based on some %age sharing.